# How can I use 'hash_map' in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm studying STL in Visual Studio Code.

I can't include 'hash_map'

```
#include <hash_map>
```

So I'm using 'unordered_map' temporarily

I wanna use 'hash_map'

Comment: There is no standard header named "hash_map".  What makes you think that's what you should use?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Visual Studio Code, `hash_map` is deprecated library. it all depends on your C++ compiler

Comment: Using `unordered_map` is just fine.

Comment: You need to get yourself a STL implementation if you are going to study STL. There are many difference between the C++ Standard Library and the Standard Template Library. This is one of them.

Comment: Thanks for all opinions.
I think that my book is old.

I'll use 'unordered_map'

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of book would teach you <hash_map>... Get a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such header in the standard and the MSDN Documentation about [`<hash_map>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x7w9f6z.aspx)[[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/hash-map-functions)] says:

> This header is obsolete. The alternative is `<unordered_map>`.

Answer (score 0):

You better have a good reason but the error message is very clear

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\hash_map(16):
>   fatal error C1189: #error:   is deprecated and will be
>   REMOVED. Please use <unordered_map>. You can define
>   _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that you have received this warning.

So just do this

```
#define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
#include <hash_map>
```

You could also add `_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS` to your project properties.

Answer (score 0):

The header is obsolete in c++11, and rename to unordered_map, reference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map